# How to Reverse a table in Mathematica?

Tags: output-formatting

This is my first time using Mathematica and for a homework assignment we were asked to print this table:

[image]

By using this code TableForm@Table[j , {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, i}] to print the table but with the 9 ones on the right and the one nine on the left. Is there some way to use table form manipulations to flip the table around horizontally, or use different logic to get the same result?

Comment: change `{j, 1,i}` to `{j, i,1,-1}`? See also [Reverse](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) and [PadLeft](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibilities

```
n = 9;
tbl = Table[If[n - i < j, n - j + 1, ""], {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}];

MatrixForm[tbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[tbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[tbl, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A `SparseArray[]` equivalent for your first snippet: `With[{n = 9}, SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; n - i < j :> n - j + 1}, {n, n}, ""] // MatrixForm]`

Answer (score 8):

You can also play with alternative ways to generate the same table:

```
table = PadLeft[Reverse /@ Range @ Range @ 9, Automatic, ""];

TeXForm @ TableForm @ table
```

> $\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  \text{} & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
>  9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}$

Also

```
table2 = Reverse /@ LowerTriangularize @ Array[#2 &, {9, 9}] /. 0 -> ""

TeXForm @ TableForm @ table2
```

> same picture

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, an additional method (I wouldn't suggest to use this though :P)

```
ConstantArray[Rotate[10 - #, -Pi/2], #] & /@ Range[9];
Rotate[Grid[%], Pi/2]
```

> [image]